# Solving $ \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial^2 t} = - c^2 w^2 ~u$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is the method to solve the following, 
where $ u = u(w,t)$ is a function of $w$ and $t$.

$ \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial^2 t} = - c^2 w^2 ~u$

My textbook simply states that the solution is $u(w,t) = A(w) \cos{(cwt)} + B(w) \sin{(cwt)}$ without explanation.

Comment: What else does your textbook say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differential equation

$$\frac{d^2 u}{dt^2}+(cw)^2u=0 \tag 1$$

is a second-order, ordinary differential equation with constant coefficients.

Solution can be obtained using a number of methodologies.

Using the methodology due to Euler, we assume that solutions are of the form $e^{st}$, where $s$ can be complex. The corresponding characteristic equation is of the form

$$s^2+(cw)^2=0\implies s=\pm iwt$$

and hence $u$ is given by

$$u=K_1(w)e^{icwt}+K_2(w)e^{-icwt}\tag 2$$

Using Euler's formula, we can write $(2)$ as

$$u=A(w)\cos(wt)+B(w)\sin(wt)$$

as was to be shown!